# Client connected to IP:port message using ASIO

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to build up a C++ 20 coroutines client for the chat server example and I'm struggling to add a message "Client connected to 127.0.0.1:666", once it establishes a connection to the server.

I'm aware of the following overload, but the problem is that it can't have `co_await` - "no instance overloaded...".

```cpp
awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    asio::async_connect(socket, endpoint,
    [&](std::error_code ec, tcp::endpoint)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Client connected to " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ":" << socket.remote_endpoint().port();
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot do that below, because of the same reason. Not allowed to use `co_await` on async_connect, because it's not awaitable.

```
awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, [](std::error_code ec)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;
            }
        });
}
```

#### Snippet

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

#include <asio.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, use_awaitable);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_context io_context;
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 666);
        tcp::socket socket(io_context);

        co_spawn(io_context, connect(std::move(socket), endpoint), detached);

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a solution. There still might be a better way tho.

```cpp
awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    std::error_code ec;
    
    co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));

    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected to " << endpoint << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix you could send a message from your server to the client if the connection is successful and react on this message.

Comment: That's not a solution. I don't want workarounds, pretty sure there is an overload to do that I'm just not so into the asio.

Comment: you could write a print statement after co_await ?
"co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, use_awaitable);"

Comment: you are mixing co_await with a callback. I think the reason you are using co_await is that you do not want to use callbacks?

Comment: maybe you are missing a "io_context.run ();" after the co_spawn?